# PHP empty array value declaration

Tags: php, arrays, declaration

Can i in some way declare an array value to be a string, int etc. without adding a value to it?

For example:

```
public $arr = array(string);
```

Comment: It's a nice idea to insist on strongly typed arrays, but you can't do this with an ordinary array. But I think you could set up a class as an [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), and refuse non-string values there, by throwing an exception.

Comment: If it is an array, its type *is* an array.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this as easier you think:

```
$arr = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no. PHP is a weakly typed language and doesn't impose types. Closest thing are [type hints](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), but those won't help you in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> PHP does not require (or support) explicit type definition in variable
>   declaration; a variable's type is determined by the context in which
>   the variable is used.

from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 1):

yes you can

```
$arr = array();
settype($arr,'string');
```

[PHP settype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php)

Comment: that's not even near to what the OP wants

Comment: can you please explain me what he want?

Comment: In short: he wants to declare a type-safe array, i.e. an array whose elements are all of a specified type. 
It's not possible with PHP arrays (albeit it's possible to simulate type-safe arrays with classes).

Comment: I've never seen this keyword before, interesting. However, it's not what the OP wants - this just recasts a value to a new type, rather than refusing to store values of the wrong type. See my comment under the Q for one approach that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an array value to be a string, int etc. without defining that value. The value `null` (which is the closest you can get to *not defining a value*) has type `null`.

Answer (score 0):

it's just thought, maybe incorrect but you can test

```
public function login()
{
    $this->index();//not done yet
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $element)
    {
        $element = '';
        // or $element = (string)$element;
    }
}
```

Maybe better way will be to use object of stdClass instead of array; or array of stdClass objects.

Comment: Ended up using stdClass object instead. Thanks for the advise.